# Can we have a list of most viewed questions?

Tags: feature-request

one day I was asking my self what are the most read/seen question on askUbunt.com ? So how about we have a featured list of the top viewed questions. This would also benefit other new Ubuntu users. For example, I was lucky enough to find this question [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance) I was checking the askUbuntu and suddenly saw this question which is really useful. Now am thinking, there are many other useful questions like this one but it is really hard to find. So with a featured list of the most viewed, most answered , or stuff like that it would make it easier for Ubuntu users to learn the hidden and beautiful tricks/tweaks to configure Ubunutu.

Comment: Are you looking for questions with [most votes](http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes)?

Comment: I was looking for most viewed. @SantoshKumar but the highest voted is also nice. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for awesomeness sometimes it's not just about views:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/greatest-hits

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for, I know awesomeness is not about views. but i want to see what people are looking for the most.

Comment: and as Stepahn mentioned below in the comment. visitors want to know these questions. So featuring them would make it easier for new Ubuntu users to find. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Ask and you shall receive](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/82571/top-x-viewed-questions?ResultSize=100)

Comment: Just tried this and after clicking the 'Run query' button all I get is `{"captcha":true}` on the page, nothing else. Firefox + NoScript (but stackexchange.com is whitelisted). Is it working for others?

Comment: Works for me, chrome, firefox, anon mode, different pcs and networks

Comment: Strange, it didn't work until I temporarily white-listed microsoft.com in NoScript. Never mind that though, well-done and it's an interesting list.

Comment: Yup its working. But you see. Am not expert like you. and many new Ubuntu users do not know how to find these qesutions. So there should be an easier method. just Like this one. http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: @Suhaib That really isn't that helpful based on this Q&A: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4070/would-adding-a-beginners-section-to-this-site-make-it-easier-to-use/4071#4071

Answer (score -1):

Most viewed is not necessarily the same as most useful

However, Most upvoted does indicate that the question is useful.

Hence, I don't see any great use in making a most-viewed list, but may be that's just me.

Comment: I disagree with your thoughts.  Both "Most viewed" and "most upvoted" have a role to play.  When you consider  there are a signicant number of users who are Not members (but visitors) to AU who cannot vote but use the site as a source of information.  Someone once told me that members only account for about 10 -15% of the sites visitors. #Views is a good indication about what visitors wnat to to know about Ubuntu.  e.g. One of my questions has over 50k views but only 40 upvotes.  It helped 40 members (AU contributors) but you cannot analyse how many it actually helped.

Comment: Agreed. Most viewed may be used as an indication of what the community wants.

Comment: I know it might not be useful to me. But there is a reason why its getting high views ! as @StephenMyall mentioned in the comment